# Received data from python SSL server is incorrect

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, server

I am trying to modify a socket server I wrote with the python socket library to use encryption using python's SSL library.

I am no able to successfully open a connection to the server, wrap it with an SSL context and send data to the server, but data sent back to the client is not what it should be.

My suspicion is that the server responses are not being decrypted on the client side, but I don't know why. I'm pretty new to SSL/TLS, and networking in general so... what am I missing?

The client is also written in python (for now, to facilitate testing)

Code:

Relevant Server stuff:

```
def sslServerLoop():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)

    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem')

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        sslConn = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_side=True)
        data = sslConn.recv(1024)
        sslConn.sendall(response)
        sslConn.close()
```

Relevant Client stuff:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile='cert.pem')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=server_addr)
s.connect((address, port))
s.sendall(msg)
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
response = s.recv(1024)
```

Sending from client to server works fine, but data sent back to the client is wrong. For example if I set `response = bytes([1])` on the server side, I receive `b'\x17\x03\x03\x00\x19\xac\xb6\x7f@\xc0\xd3\xce%\x13G\x01\xbd\x88y\xf0\xda..\x02\xf9\xe4o\xdd\x1a\xdb'` on the client side. Most of that changes every time I try to run it, but the first 5 bytes are always the same (which is partly why I suspect it isn't being decrypted).

cert.pem is a self signed certificate generated using openssl as described in the python 3 SSL module documentation

Comment: *"...what am I missing?"* - your are missing code in your question which demonstrates the problem you have. Based on your description only it is impossible to say what you did wrong because it is impossible to see what you did in the first place. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is your Code?

Comment: Added code samples, sorry about that. Wasn't thinking I needed them for this question.

Comment: Removing or moving s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) as suggested causes the client to neither get a response nor complete. I end up having to ctr-c out.

Comment: Please try to make your examples complete: specifically, you haven't shown where "response" is defined in the server code, and you should show both the output you *expect* and what you're actually getting. The "data sent back to the client is not what it should be" might make sense to you, how do you expect anyone else to know what that means?

Comment: They aren't static, this isn't just like an echo server or something. As an example when I try to send a single byte 0x01 the client receives this: 0x170303001931ad239e143e3723259e12c094720d30c12435fd48359bf94b

Comment: It is not legal to shutdown a socket that is being used for SSL. It is a protocol violation. You must close via the SSL API you are using.

Comment: And are you sure this is the real client code? You're not receiving via the plaintext socket? The data you show corresponds to TLS `{record_type=application_data, tls_version=1.3, length=0, ...}`.

Comment: Yes it is the real code. Or rather a simplified version that has the exact same issue. I tested it as written here. I believe the python SSL module does in fact use TLS not SSL.

Comment: The comment seems to have disappeared that suggested that the problem was the s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) line, but that turns out to be the answer. When I tested that earlier I mistakenly tested the suggestion using my actual code rather than the example code posted here. Turns out something else is causing the socket to block without that line in my code, and that line was the culprit afterall. If you see this feel free to post that as an answer and I will give credit where credit is due. (Also hope I didn't accidentally delete that comment...

Comment: You can only delete your own comments, not other people's. So he must have deleted it himself. Didn't believe it himself maybe?  But he wasn't the only person to say so :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not legal to shutdown a socket that is being used for SSL. It is a protocol violation. You must close via the SSL/TLS API you are using.

Comment: Evidently Python's SSL `shutdown()` performs, bizarrely, and undocumentedly, something akin to its `unwrap()`, restoring the socket to plaintext.